# Python script for summing values in list continuously

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make a function "add" that will be able to sum elements of list continuously and return a new list of sums. In python there can be cases where input is not a list, or there are other objects in it instead of integers like string characters or float numbers, in these cases I have to return 'Invalid input'

Eg :

```
add([1,2,3,4,5]) == [1, 3, 6, 10, 15] , because it's calculated like this : [1, 1 + 2, 1 + 2 + 3, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5]

add([1,'a',2,'b',3,'c']) == 'Invalid input'

add('All string') == 'Invalid input'

add((1,2,3,4)) == 'Invalid input'
```

How do I do it?

Comment: In pure python? You're looking for a cumulative sum, or `.cumsum()` in numpy.

Comment: why is the last one bad input? learn about [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)

Answer (score 1):

numpy cumsum is likely the most adapted to what you are looking for:

```
import numpy

data = numpy.array([ndx**2 for ndx in range(10)])
numpy.cumsum(data)
```

#### output:

```
array([  0,   1,   5,  14,  30,  55,  91, 140, 204, 285])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two levels in this.

---

1. Find if elements in the list are all `int` :

   ```
   >>> all(isinstance(ele , int) for ele in l)
   ```

   If its `false` : *print invalid* ; otherwise *continue* with the computation.

---

2. Give the cumulative sum of previous elements :

   ```
   >>> [sum( l[:i+1] ) for i in range(len(l))]
   ```

---

#driver values :

```
IN : l = [1,2,3,4,5]
OUT : True                          #all ints
      [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]

IN : l = [1,'a',2,'b',3,'c']
OUT : False                        #not int
      Invalid input
```

---

Or, an even easier method following `try/except` methodology :

```
try : 
     print([sum( l[:i+1] ) for i in range(len(l))]) 
except : 
     print("Invalid Input")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to get cumsum followed by `any(isinstance(i,str) for i in list)` to validate if any element is string

```
from itertools import accumulate

l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
print ("Invalid input" if any(isinstance(i, str) for i in l1) else list(accumulate(l1)))
#[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]

l2 = [1,2,3,'str',5]
print ("Invalid input" if any(isinstance(i, str) for i in l2) else list(accumulate(l2)))
#Invalid input
```

Putting in function:

```
def cumsum(l):
    if any(isinstance(i, str) for i in l):
        print ('Invalid input')
    else:
        print (list(accumulate(l1)))

cumsum([1,2,3,4,5])
#[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
cumsum([1,2,3,'str',5])
#Invalid input
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def add_up(nums):
   if any(not isinstance(n, int) for n in nums):
      return 'Invalid input'
   def gen():
      n = nums[0]
      yield n
      for i in nums[1:]:
          n = i + n
          yield n
   return list(gen())
```

**Result**

```
add_up([1,2,3,4,5])
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]

add_up([1,'a',2,'b',3,'c'])
'Invalid input'

add_up('All string')
'Invalid input'

add_up(['a','b','c'])
'Invalid input'

add_up(range(10))
[0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45]
```

Comment: Better to call your function after validating the input I think

Comment: @VanPeer agree.

Answer (score 0):

we can use numpy cumsum to get the list of cumulative values.

```
import numpy as np
def cumSum(arr):
    try:
        return (list(np.cumsum(arr)))
    except:
        return "inValid"
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(cumSum(a))
```

the above snippet output is

```
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import accumulate

def add(input):
    if all(isinstance(i,int) for i in  input):
        return list(accumulate(input))
    else:
        return "invalid input"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the method that sum up only a valid int or float list

```html
def add(lis):
    if not isIntList(lis) or type(lis) is not list:
       return False
    return [sum(lis[:x+1]) for x in range(len(lis))]
```

the method check if the values in the list are int or float values

```html
def isIntList(list):
    for i in list:
        if not isinstance(i, int) and not isinstance(i, float):
            return False
    return True
```